# Using Chicagoboss boss_db and printing list of records

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I'm trying to print a list of records from mnesia.

```
Users = boss_db:find(users, []),
lists:foreach(fun(X) ->         
[{_,Email,_,_,_,_,AccessToken}] = X,
io:format("Email : ~w~n",[Email]),
io:format("AccessToken : ~w~n",[AccessToken]), end, [Users]).
```

However I'm getting:

Email : [117,115,101,..,..,.,..]

Similarly for AccessToken.

What am I missing? Any pointer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't choose the right format: ~w is used to print as erlang term, ~s is used for string, ~p for pretty print, it tries to find the best way to print . See doc at http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-3

```
1> L = "Hello".
"Hello"
2> io:format("~w~n",[L]).
[72,101,108,108,111]
ok
3> io:format("~p~n",[L]).
"Hello"
ok
4> io:format("~s~n",[L]).
Hello
ok
5> L1 = [1,2,3,4,5].     
[1,2,3,4,5]
6> io:format("~w~n",[L1]).
[1,2,3,4,5]
ok
7> io:format("~p~n",[L1]).
[1,2,3,4,5]
ok
8> io:format("~s~n",[L1]).
^A^B^C^D^E
ok
9>
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal...appreciate your quick answer.